# Angular Material renders only part of form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I made a form using Angular Material, but it renders only partial, and after I click on a field, the rest of the inputs appear.

I uninstalled and installed Node and Angular... I am using the last version (until today). Not resolved.

I followed these instructions: https://alligator.io/angular/angular-material-2/

The code of app.component:

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Nome</mat-label>
    <input type="text" ngModel name="Nome" matInput required>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>E-mail</mat-label>
    <input type="email" ngModel name="Email" matInput required>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Senha</mat-label>
    <input type="password" ngModel name="Senha" matInput required>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>xxx</mat-label>
    <input type="text" ngModel name="xxxxxxx" matInput required>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>yyy</mat-label>
    <input type="text" ngModel name="yyyyyyy" matInput required>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

When I open the localhost:4200 only 2 fields appear, but I expected to see all fields.
After I click or enter on the first field, the other fields show...

I Inspect using Chrome, and I sow that the DOM elements (the last ones) were created only after I click on the first field. (I saw a kind of flash in inspector).

Just after ng serve

[image: just after ng serve]

After click on the first field:

[image: after click on the first field]

Comment: try to check console in such case! any error or warning there?

Answer (score 0):

the code seems to be working when I run it on stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xs8zfq

try this once

in pollyfills.ts

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

in styles.css

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Comment: Hi!!
I tried now what you suggested, but it did not work yet.
Even so, thank you a lot.
And have a happy new year!

Comment: Everything seems to be correct in the code you shared. check with ur .ts file once.

Comment: Anil, Thanks for your suggestion... I created a new app now (following the instructions above), and It not work again. Oh my G...

Answer (score 0):

my friends.

It seams that this behavior is caused by Angular 7.

Why? I ran the code inside an Angular 6.x version Core and it worked!

I did not find yet how to control this behavior, but I will find the solution - or you, of course.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?